# Cmd command to delete all subfolders of a directory and remake them with the same name

Tags: loops, for-loop, cmd, subdirectory

I wrote the follow cmd command:

```
for /d %a in (C:\Vendita\*) do set ("folderName=%a" & rmdir %folderName% & md %folderName%)
```

to iterate trought all 1st level subdirectory of a folder (C:\Vendita), save each subfolder name in a variable called "folderName", remove each subdirectory and remake each subdirectory using the saved name.
I have tryed to execute it but it doeasn't work.

what is wrong?

thank you

Comment: you'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). Or use `%a` directly (you don't need a variable): `for /d %a in (C:\Vendita\*) do rmdir /s /q "%a" & md "%a"`

Comment: it works, thank you